# Lags on a specific Windows 10 installation over MS VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, lag

I have a Windows 10 machine that is connected over MS VPN to a company intranet.
All traffic to this company intranet and to the internet go over the VPN.

When using remote desktop over the VPN the input/response lags significantly thus rendering it useless.
I encountered that this seems to be the case for every traffic over the VPN and not just remote desktop.
Even for pinging: [http://imgur.com/dvxmcma](https://imgur.com/dvxmcma) (too little rep to post image directly)

The screenshot shows the result of two `ping xxx -t -w 10000` commands that ran at the same time. One is going to google.at the other to a server in the intranet. You can see that there are very long ping times roughly every 10 seconds or something for both commands.

Curious thing is, that on another windows 10 box on the same network which is connected to the same VPN these lags do not occur at all. So it seems that some network setting on this particular box is set wrong.

I tried to re-setup the VPN connection without luck.

I would hate to reinstall windows 10 on that box for some silly reason like that. Maybe you can help me out.

Comment: You can try a refresh if you think something is wrong with the systems OS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I will have to do that if there is no other way.